# What is the meaning of "$cm->course" in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I am new at PHP and currently now i am working on moodle LMS tool.

I am referring view.php of scorm package and dont know why `$cm->course` this is used in php.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: referencing course property of cm object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2009/03/04/php-operators-double-and-single-arrow/)
"->" means accessing the `$cm` object property `course`

Answer (score 1):

$cm is an object, and course is a variable. Here you can see brief of PHP syntax with objects:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 1):

> PHP has two Object Operator namely -> and ::
>
> -> is used when you are trying to call a method on an Instance and / or access an Instance property.
>
> :: is used when you want to call a static method or call a parent
>   class's version of a method within a child class.

Reference: https://www.codeproject.com/questions/196270/what-is-meant-by-symbol-in-php

Note: I googled your exact question and got this result!

Answer (score 1):

It is "object operator" - [T_OBJECT_OPERATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php). It is used to access properties and methods of class on an object.